# 21.04: Cannot launch Audacious from command line: "D-Bus error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY"

Tags: dbus, 21.04, audacious

Launching [the Audacious audio player](https://audacious-media-player.org/developers) from the command line yields the following error:

```
$ audacious 
ERROR dbus-server.cc:928 [dbus_server_init]: D-Bus error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
ERROR pulse_audio.cc:439 [create_context]: pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
WARNING plugin-init.cc:110 [start_plugin]: PulseAudio Output failed to start.
ERROR plugin.cc:310 [init]: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
WARNING plugin-init.cc:110 [start_plugin]: MPRIS 2 Server failed to start.

(audacious:42484): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:18:52.181: cannot open display: 
WARNING main.cc:328 [main_cleanup]: exit() called unexpectedly; skipping normal cleanup.
```

Launching Audacious from the dash works without any problems, as well as opening files with it or starting it from the context menu in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.04 starts Wayland by default. So you got no X11 $DISPLAY.

In you login screen is a small cog on the right side,

[[image: 1]]

change it to "Ubuntu" an login again...

Comment: Thanks, @kanehekili! So this means, Audacious is not compatible with Wayland? Or is it a general Ubuntu problem? Why does launching via the other mentioned methods work?

Comment: The Menu looks different on my installation: only two entries - "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Xorg". Selecting the latter indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant: with 21.04 Wayland is default and X11 only the backup. (Picture is from 20.04) Audacious is compatible with wayland as it uses GTK3 - which must support wayland. But "dbus" (the interprocess communication) can't reach X11 anymore - thus can't start the app from terminal in order to pass a display.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Still I wonder: What must happen to make launching Audacious from the terminal work again on Ubuntu using Wayland? Who has to fix what? I suppose other apps are affected too, and launching from the command line is still a supported feature?