# nvidia video card - X11 was working - system update changed default to wayland - now system is unstable

Tags: nvidia, xorg

How can I change from wayland to x11?

UBUNTU 22.04.1 LTS was installed from scratch after the upgrade from 20.04 LTS failed due to problems with PYTHON 3.

I CAN NOT USE THE cog on the right-hand bottom edge of the screen to change the display manager, because the gear icon is NOT displayed.

The logon gear is NOT displayed on my screen, probably because it is too close to the edge. My SAMSUNG 4k monitor overscans, and until I'm logged on and can change the resolution and set an UNDERSCAN of 75, the outside 100 pixels or so in all directions are NOT displayed...

The monitor is a Samsung LU28E570ds/ZA (28" UE570) with a single "joystick" like button on back to control standard brightness/contrast/color/sharpness and video source (2 HDMI, 1 Display port) I use the HDMI because that is what my video card (NVIDIA GeForce GT-710) outputs.

so how do I change the default to X11?

(4 nov) I do have it running with X11 now, but now have problems with screen freeze after suspend. I have separate report open on that issue.

Comment: log out. On login select the cogg on the right lower side and select the XServer. [Look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340234/906933) Might look different -you did not bother to mention your Ubuntu version

Comment: Kanehekili, thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the description to specify the UBUNTU version, and have attempted to clarify why I can not use the trick you suggested.

Comment: What Nvidia card and which driver are you using?  The Wayland/Xorg default depends upon both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanetely disable Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland)

Comment: Kanehekili - That is a partial answer. it also required the "DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop" statement as identified by MDebusk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://fostips.com/switch-back-xorg-ubuntu-21-04/):

```bash
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line that reads: `#WaylandEnable=false`

Under it, add the following line: `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop`

Comment: MDeBusk, I have done as you suggested, and am now running as X11. I will let this run for a day or so, and will then tag this as resolved. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I'm glad to know it worked. Now to figure out how to get your monitor to scan correctly.

Comment: copy of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428525/how-to-permanetely-disable-wayland)

Comment: MDeBusk - thank you system now "stable". Can not fix "scan" it is a monitor hardware issue. With Nvidia-settings I can set underscan to 75 pixel and everything is displayed "full screen". don't know of anyway to set this BEFORE I am logged on. Monitor can display 3840x2160 but age and eyesight I usually set to 2560x1440.

Comment: @kanehekili Not precisely, but I get what you're aiming at. I linked in my answer where I originally found the information.

Comment: @wb4alm Is there no way to set the hardware up to suit you? I know there are usually settings in TV sets to change overscan.